# Git rebase private branch to latest of master

Tags: git, github

```
A---B---C---D   -> master
    \
     E---F      -> Branch1(separate remote branch)
```

The above one is the current and the goal is the below,

```
 A---B---C---D      -> master
             \
             E---F -> Branch1 (separate remote branch)
```

How to achieve in git? Need to move my private branch to latest of master and apply my changes on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch1
git rebase master
```

Comment: Fetch and pull? Why not just pull?

Comment: Fab. All is well